# Align inline ordered DIVs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I align part of child divs inline if I use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` for the paternal div?

I tried to use `display: inline-block` for the child divs, also `float:left`, but no one of this work.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item
{
  border: 1px dotted;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.item1 {
  order: 2;
}
.item2 {
  order: 1;
}
.item3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item1 item" >2</div>
  <div class="item2 item" >1</div>
  <div class="item3 item" >3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-direction: row;

Comment: Do you want to align in horizontal row.?

Comment: @Aman yes, horizontal .

Comment: use align-items: center; instead of flex-direction: column; at #container.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.item
{
  border: 1px dotted;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item1 {
  order: 2;
  display: block;
}
.item2 {
  order: 1;
  float: left;
}
.item3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item1 item" >2</div>
  <div class="item2 item" >1</div>
  <div class="item3 item" >3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I wrote in my question, "align part of child divs inline", not all divs inline.

Comment: What parts are you talking about. Please elaborate.

Comment: For example, item1 single in 1 line, and item2 and item3 align together in next line.

Comment: is there any compulsion to use display:flex? Will it be useful if there is another method?

Comment: I just checked it again and noticed that the order does not work!

Comment: Well order property work with flex only and the solution i provided does not have flex it is using inline-block.

Comment: Check this, order will work here but you need to change the css for current top box. as flex attach element with order and so its css also get attache with that.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item  { display: flex; }
.item1 { flex: 1 0 45%; order: 2; }
.item2 { flex: 1 0 60%; order: 1; }
.item3 { flex: 1 0 45%; order: 3; }

.item > span {
  border: 1px dotted;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item2 > span { margin: 0 auto;    }
.item1 > span { margin-left: auto; }
.item3 > span { margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item1 item"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="item2 item"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="item3 item"><span>3</span></div>
</div>
```